# Generic "Judicial" rules of order?

Tags: due-process, parliamentary-procedure

[This question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/23415/courtroom-rules-of-order?r=SearchResults) asks for a Roberts Rules analogue for, specifically, courtroom proceedings.  However, other non-governmental organizations often need to decide someone's fate within the organization based on evidence and witness testimony, etc.  For example, a union employee may be disciplined for some action, and there are typically some kind of rules laid out for conducting the proceedings against said employee as negotiated between the union and the employer.

I am curious if there exist any Roberts Rules analogues that might be applicable to this sort of generic NGO judicial proceedings?

Note that I am not interested in, e.g., federal rules etc. but only in "generic" rules that can be adopted by arbitrary organizations.

Comment: The American Arbitration Association has published rules that might be relevant. https://www.adr.org/sites/default/files/CommercialRules_Web_FINAL_2.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I can't say that I have ever seen a "generic" set of rules for quasi-judicial proceedings made for adoption by NGOs.

I drafted a set once for the University of Michigan's student government, and I have seen others in use (most recently for quasi-judicial proceedings concerning zoning variances before a municipal Board of Adjustment). So, there are many examples to borrow from, but I don't know of a standard set with the equivalent of the wide spread adoption by reference seen for Robert's Rules of Order.

Comment: This was my suspicion from my brief search, but I had hoped that my search skills were simply lacking.